# Scrollable StackView inside a UITableViewCell - ScrollView ContentSize not being updated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uistackview

*I've recently started learning swift and iOS app development. I've been doing php backend and low level iOS/macOS programming till now and working with UI is a little hard for me, so please tolerate my stupidity.*

If I understand this correctly, stackviews automatically space and contain its subviews in its frame. All the math and layout is done automatically by it. I have a horizontal stackview inside a custom `UITableViewCell`. The `UIStackView` is within a `UIScrollView` because I want the content to be scroll-able. I've set the anchors programmatically (I just can't figure out how to use the storyboard thingies). [This is what the cells look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksI9m.png)

When I load the view, the stackview doesn't scroll. But it does scroll if I select the cell at least once. The `contentSize` of the scrollview is set inside the layoutsubviews method of my custom cell.

My Custom Cell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    let stackViewLabelContainer  = UIStackView()
    let scrollViewContainer = UIScrollView()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = .black
        stackViewLabelContainer.axis = .horizontal
        stackViewLabelContainer.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackViewLabelContainer.alignment = .leading
        stackViewLabelContainer.spacing = 5
        for _ in 1...10
        {
            let labelView = UILabel();
            labelView.backgroundColor = tintColor
            labelView.textColor = .white
            labelView.text = "ABCD 123"

            stackViewLabelContainer.addArrangedSubview(labelView)
        }
        scrollViewContainer.addSubview(stackViewLabelContainer)
        stackViewLabelContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackViewLabelContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackViewLabelContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollViewContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        addSubview(scrollViewContainer)
        scrollViewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo:stackViewLabelContainer.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false



    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews()
    {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        scrollViewContainer.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackViewLabelContainer.frame.width, height: stackViewLabelContainer.frame.height)

    }





}
```

Here's the TableViewController

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuse_cell")

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 5
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuse_cell") as! TableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        print("called")
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
//        let cells  = tableView.visibleCells as! Array<TableViewCell>
//        cells.forEach
//        {
//            cell in
//            cell.scrollViewContainer.contentSize = CGSize(width: cell.stackViewLabelContainer.frame.width, height: cell.stackViewLabelContainer.frame.height)
//
//        }
    }

}
```

I figured out a method to make this work but it affects abstraction and it feels like a weird hack. You get the visible cells from within the UITableViewController, access each scrollview and update its contentSize. There's another fix I found by reversing dyld_shared_cache where I override `draw` method and stop reusing cells. Both solutions feel like they're far from "proper".

Answer (score 0):

You should constraint the scrollview to the contentView of the cell.

```
contentView.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Now you can loop your labels and add them as the arranged subviews

```
for _ in 1...10
{
                let labelView = UILabel();
                labelView.backgroundColor = tintColor
                labelView.textColor = .white
                labelView.text = "ABCD 123"

                stackView.addArrangedSubview(labelView)
 }
```